# Winsock2.h seems to be missing from mingw?

Tags: c, linux, windows, mingw, cross-compiling

I have installed mingw on my arch linux distribution in order to cross compile windows applications. Everything seems to work fine, except when I include Winsock2:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -Wall  -o tcp.o tcp.c
tcp.c:14:24: fatal error: Winsock2.h: No such file or directory
#include <Winsock2.h>
```

What package do I miss?

Comment: try installing  mingw-w64-headers-git-4.0.rc1.r183.g5e2e73b-1-any.pkg.tar.xz or equivalent.  I peaked in the archive and saw winsock.h and winsock2.h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that in linux, files paths are case sensitive. On Windows you can do:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
```

while the actual file is `C:/Path/To/Include/winsock2.h`

On linux you have to do

```
#include <winsock2.h>
```